# Babel/Core-JS not finding own files -- AWS EB Django

Tags: django, npm, babeljs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having a hard time getting ReactJS and all its dependencies working properly on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. Currently, I'm trying to get Babel to work. It doesn't seem to know where it has installed itself to -- what folder it's in. For example, you should be able to use `"@babel/preset-env"` for a preset name, but I've found I need to give the full path, `"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/@babel/preset-env"`, or else it won't be able to find it. (Similar with other presets/plugins.)

I've gotten most things into a working state using this approach, except for core-js. It seems to be looking in /tmp/ to find its own modules. Weird, but I was able to add a symbolic link from there to its actual location. But now, it can't find `core-js/modules/es.string.split`. I looked in the real modules folder and sure enough, that file doesn't exist.

So my question is, what is the file `es.string.split` (apart from the obvious -- some polyfill for String.split), why is it not looking for e.g. `es6.string.split` (which also doesn't exist), why is it missing, etc. etc. How do I get this to work.

Error message I'm getting:

```
[Application update [...]/Command 02_compress] : Activity execution failed, because: CommandError: An error occurred during rendering [...my_template].html: Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es.string.split' from '/tmp'
  at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
  at process (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
  at ondir (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
  at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
  at onex (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
  at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
```

Installation .ebextensions file:

```
# approach taken from https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/install-nodejs.config

files:
  "/tmp/prep_node_installation.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

  "/tmp/install_node.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      yum -y install nodejs

  "/tmp/install_npm.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      curl --silent --location http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

  "/tmp/install_babel.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
      npm install --save core-js@3 @babel/polyfill
      npm install -g browserify

      # For some reason, core-js seems to be looking in /tmp/ for its files. So place a symbolic link from there to the actual folder that has the files.
      ln -sf /opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/@babel/polyfill/node_modules/core-js /tmp/core-js


commands:
  05_prep_for_node_install:
    command: "sh /tmp/prep_node_installation.sh"
    ignoreErrors: false

  10_install_node:
    command: "sh /tmp/install_node.sh"
    ignoreErrors: false

  20_install_npm:
    command: "sh /tmp/install_npm.sh"
    ignoreErrors: false

  30_install_babel:
    command: "sh /tmp/install_babel.sh"
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Babel config.js file:

```js
const presets = [
  [
    // Because "@babel/preset-env" doesn't work...
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/@babel/preset-env",
    {
      targets: {
        edge: "17",
        firefox: "60",
        chrome: "67",
        safari: "11.1",
        ie: "11",
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 3,
    },
  ],
  [
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/@babel/preset-react",
    {}
  ],
];

const plugins = [
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```

My application was already set up to use Django-Compressor, so this is the command that runs Babel in preparation for compressing, from settings.py:

```py
_babel_executable = os.environ.get(
    'BABEL_EXECUTABLE',
    # Full path because it can't find the `babel` executable either
    '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/node_modules/.bin/babel'
)
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = [
    ('text/javascript',
     ('cat {infile} | %s -f {infile} > {outfile}.tmp;' % _babel_executable) +
     'browserify {outfile}.tmp -o {outfile}'),

    ('text/jsx',
     ('cat {infile} | %s -f {infile} > {outfile}.tmp;' % _babel_executable) +
     'browserify {outfile}.tmp -o {outfile}'),
]
```

Comment: Have you installed the `core-js` module it is expecting?

Comment: The entire relevant installation is included in the files above. You can see the `core-js@3` installation as part of the .ebextensions file, about halfway down, under the "/tmp/install_babel.sh" section. How would I go about finding what modules I need and installing them?

Answer (score 0):

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra/package.json'

From an official AWS thread[1], it appears (and this was my problem) that you might be zipping the top-level directory rather than zipping the source itself.

For example, you may have all of your files in a folder called "Project". Rather than zipping "Project", you should zip and upload the contents of "Project".

[1] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=476022

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But this is a Python/Django environment on which I'm installing Node.js, not a Node.js native environment. The Django portion works fine until I try to install Node/Babel/React, and if I put a package.json it gets ignored.

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/#why-cant-they-be-fixed

This is a probable explanation for the failure. The package manager is yarn but I'm sure it applies to npm as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to mismatch in the install directories for Browerify.

The execution of $ npm install -g browserify will globally search for installation files and not in the npm directory set in AWS.

Comment: I assume then that your solution is to not use the `-g` flag? (Please put your proposed solution into the answer)